# 2 way communication in python between a qt application and an external software

Tags: python, sockets, blender

I am working on a program which can communicate with an Addon in Blender3D.

I need to be able to communicate between these two scripts (both python).
Ideally something where I could call a function when a message is received and then have that function handle the contents of the message and what to do with it.

I have tried using sockets but haven't been able to get the desired result. I also want to avoid the program/rest of the script to hang while its waiting for signals as there are other things that it will need to be doing in the mean time.

Cheers

Comment: Can you show what have you tried? Maybe someone could tell you why the code using sockets is failing.

Comment: The sockets aren't failing. I am able to send and receive a message. My issue however is that I am unsure how to approach a system that lets me send a message at any time, and then process that message. Also with the rest of the application still functioning in the background.